# Taking out the last characther from the string, storing it into the variable and then deleting it using Regex C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string, char

I have a string like following (for example):

```
   Testing stackoverflow 6
   Testing stackoverflow 67
   Testing stackoverflow 687
   Testing stackoverflow 6789
```

Now I know for a fact that every time the string is gonna end up with a number value. I need to take out this number... It can be a number anywhere in between 1 to 5000... I figured that using lambda expressions wouldn't help since I can't really determine how big will the number be, so I figured regex might be a good way to solve this, but how ?

Edit:

When I take out the number from regex and storing it like this:

```
int somevalue = Convert.ToInt32(whatever regex takes out);
// Now I have to remove the number from the string...
```

Anyone has any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var match = Regex.Match(myString, @"\d+$");
if(match != null) {
    long ret;
    long.TryParse(match.Groups[0].Value, out ret);
    myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"\d+$", "");
}
```

The regex match only if there is a number at the end of the string and declaring ret as  `long` permit you to cover the case where ret is longer than `int.MaxValue`

Comment: Okay and how can I remove the number from the string once I get the actual number ? :)

Comment: Now it also replace the number with string.Empty

Comment: It says cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Match'... Any ideas?

Comment: I'm an idiot, sorry. Edited again. `match` is an object which contains a list of `Group` where are stored the matches

Answer (score 1):

```
int number = 0;
string test = "Testing stackoverflow 6789";
string[] testArr = test.Split(' ');

int.TryParse(testArr[testArr.Length - 1], out number);

//you have the value in the number variable.
```

Comment: Does this works regardless of long the number is?? It can be 3-4-5 digits? How can I remove the number from the string once I take out the number

Comment: @User987 Yes, doesn't matter how long is the number. You can test it easily.

Comment: Okay this works quite well. I love it, how can I remove the number out of the string right away after I took out the number? :D

Comment: @User987 I don't understand you. You have your number in the number variable after that you can use it whatever you like. If the question help you mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex:

```
string pattern = @"^.+ (\d+)$";
string input = "Testing stackoverflow 6789";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.None, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500));
int? output;

if (match != null)
{
    string groupValue = match.Groups[1].Value;
    output = Convert.ToInt32(groupValue); 
}
```

Comment: Hey there, the pattern isn't as "Testing stackoverflow" ... The text before the number can be anything, the only thing I know for a fact is that the string ends up with the number lol

Comment: Will there always be a space before the number?  I've updated.

Comment: Yes, and once I get the actual number, I'll need to remove it from the string... How can I remove it from the string once I fetch it ?

Comment: See the `output` variable in my example?  It's a nullable int.  Just check if it has a value with `output.HasValue` then get the value, if it does have one, with `output.Value`.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "Testing stackoverflow 6";
long value = 0;
bool b = long.TryParse(str.Split(' ').Last(), out value);
```

To Split on the basis of Space , Get the Last string and convert it to long or int